# Problem with subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

In my current working directory I have the dir ROOT/ with some files inside.

I know I can exec `cp -r ROOT/* /dst` and I have no problems.

But if I open my Python console and I write this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['cp', '-r', 'ROOT/*', '/dst'])
```

It doesn't work!

I have this error: `cp: cannot stat ROOT/*: No such file or directory`

Can you help me?

Comment: For this example, you should probably just use [`shutil.copytree`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree), which does exactly that (recursive directory copying).

Answer (score 10):

Just came across this while trying to do something similar.

> The * will not be expanded to filenames

Exactly. If you look at the man page of `cp` you can call it with any number of source arguments and you can easily change the order of the arguments with the `-t` switch.

```
import glob
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['cp', '-rt', '/dst'] + glob.glob('ROOT/*'))
```

Comment: Actually, I think this needs to be something like `subprocess.call(['cp', '-rt', '/dst'] + glob.glob('ROOT/*'))` since glob returns a list.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
subprocess.call('cp -r ROOT/* /dst', shell=True)
```

Note the use of a single string rather than an array here.

Or build up your own implementation with [listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

Comment: Yes, it works... And I think it's exactly the same as os.system... Is it right?

Comment: I don't want to use shell=True, so is there any other way?

Comment: @Rahul: Try http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html (and sorry for the late reply!)

Answer (score 4):

The `*` will not be expanded to filenames. This is a function of the shell. Here you actually want to copy a file named *. Use `subprocess.call()` with the parameter `shell=True`.

Comment: Right! That was Popen(). Sorry.

Comment: Don't you think I could simply use:

os.system('cp -r ROOT/* /dst')

This seems to work...

Comment: Maybe you can use the glob module to build the list of files you want to copy and pass the filenames to subprocess.call().

Comment: os.system() actually executes the command through a subshell. The filename expansion is then done by the shell.

Comment: Old question but very helpful for a similar error on Windows.  The same limitation applies -- "\*.\*" doesn't get expanded unless you set shell=True.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the command as list instead of the string + list.

The following two commands are same:-

```
First Command:-
test=subprocess.Popen(['rm','aa','bb'])

Second command:-
list1=['rm','aa','bb']
test=subprocess.Popen(list1)
```

So to copy multiple files, one need to get the list of files using blob and then add 'cp' to the front of list and destination to the end of list and provide the list to subprocess.Popen().

Like:-

```
list1=blob.blob("*.py")
list1=['cp']+list1+['/home/rahul']
xx=subprocess.Popen(list1)
```

It will do the work.